# getting id of trigger in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let me preface this by making 2 things clear: I am extremely well aware that the way that you send an Id is like this:

```
onclick="sendMyId(this.id);"

function sendMyId(id){
}
```

Done it what feels like a million times.

Secondly, I am looking for a pure javascript way of doing this. No libraries, no plugins, addons, magical rituals or JQuery.

Knowing that. Can we do it the other way around and get the id of the element it was sent from? can we get it from the event maybe? Or maybe just some events, but not all? does the document element save the id of whatever triggered smething? I just need some way of accessing it.

```
function sentId(e, val) {
    id = e.id_of_something_that_sent_it_somehow;
}
```

Why? Just to cut down on the amount of variables I send. Designing a new function for sending data right now, and if I could pass this:

```
onclick="sendToHandler('refreshElem', 'txt=test', 'testDiv', 'testCallback');
```

instead of this:

```
onclick="sendToHandler('refreshElem', 'txt=test', this, 'testDiv', 'testCallback');
```

it'd make it slightly easier to read.

...and getting the Id once in the function rather than from a gazillion different functions spread throughout the system just seems cleaner and more appealing to me somehow.

So...can it be done? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use `event` which is always passed to event handlers. Is this what you are looking for:

```js
function call(a,b){
  console.log(a,b,event.target.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="hello" onclick="call(23,33)">X</button>
```

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I didn't realize we both posted at the same time. You should not have deleted your answer, it was a timing issue.